# What is the best way to play video in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I'm trying to make auto-play video in *UITableViewCell* depending on cell position.

I'm using the *AVPlayer*

Here is my code:

```
    __weak typeof(self)this = self;

    NSString* videoPath = @"http://test.com/test.mp4";
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath] options:nil];
    NSArray* keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"playable",nil];

    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^(){
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        this.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        this.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:this.avPlayer];
        this.avPlayerLayer.frame = _videoContent.frame;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [this.videoContent.layer addSublayer:this.avPlayerLayer];
            [this.avPlayer play];
        });
    }];
```

But my UITableView is frozen when i scroll the table.
I think there are many time-consuming work but most biggest thing is

```
[this.avPlayer play]
```

So my question is that AVPlayer is the best way in this situation?
And is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: You can use MPMoviePlayerController instead of AVPlayer. You can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754933/playing-videos-in-uitableviewcell), for more specific details of how to use it in cell.

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh I have tried but I think that MPMoviePlayerController is not faster than AVPlayer. Thanks :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use the below link , this suits for your question.

https://github.com/PRX/PRXPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that creating the `AVPlayerItem`, `AVPlayer`, and `AVPlayerLayer` can all be performed off the main thread? You might want to try putting those inside the block that dispatches on the main queue.

Comment: I already try it because i'm not sure it needs to run in main thread or not. But it is same. Thanks :)